# How to change the hwid in the msi file Check_HardwareId looks for on the system?

Tags: windows-installer, driver

I don't have any experience with ms installer, so I need help with this:

Manufacturer confirmed this is the same as another hardware, except for pcb aesthetics and hwid. So far I'm using InstEd.

I got an installer for drivers, already edited inf and ini files, updated file table in the msi file and so on.

Msi installer starts ISSetup.dll entry:f6 (guessing this is check hwid), but I just can't find where is that hwid is stored.

EDIT: More details. 
At the CustomActions in the msi there is the:
Check_HardwareID 0x101 ISSetup.dll f6.

msiexec logging result:

```
CustomAction Check_HardwareID returned actual error code 1602 (note this may not be 100% accurate if translation happened inside sandbox)
MSI (c) (20:84) [23:10:06:554]: NOTE: custom action Check_HardwareID unexpectedly closed the hInstall handle (type MSIHANDLE) provided to it. The custom action should be fixed to not close that handle.
Action ended 23:10:06: Check_HardwareID. Return value 2.
MSI (c) (20:E8) [23:10:06:554]: Doing action: SetupInterrupted
```

This msi looks for another hardware I don't have and I would like to modify the other installer to work with  mine.

EDIT2: If I remove the custom action (checkhardwareid) then it says: requires win10 or later. But I got win 10!

How to see what exactly LaunchConditions is doing? Apparently there are some other difference between the 2 devices, I have reason to believe it's minimal.

```
MSI (c) (94:1C) [12:36:14:429]: Doing action: LaunchConditions
Action 12:36:14: LaunchConditions. Evaluating launch conditions
Action start 12:36:14: LaunchConditions.
Info 2898.For Tahoma8 textstyle, the system created a 'Tahoma' font, in 1 character set.
[x] requires that your computer is running Windows 10 or later.
MSI (c) (94:1C) [12:36:17:199]: Product: [x] requires that your computer is running Windows 10 or later.
Action ended 12:36:17: LaunchConditions. Return value 3.
MSI (c) (94:1C) [12:36:17:199]: Doing action: SetupCompleteError
```

EDIT: I know this now, there is a table with the conditions. Still have problems with the driver but that is not covered by this topic.

**As for the question in the title... Still curious!**

Help me if you can

Thank You.

Comment: As it is, it's difficult to truly understand your problem. Could you explain it in a little bit more detail?

Comment: Can you not just bypass/remove that custom action?

Comment: If I remove the custom action (checkhardwareid) then it says: requires win10 or later.
But I got win 10! How to bypass?

Comment: well, the bypass works, there are other checks I have to bypass as it seems :(